# mkdir() not working when hitting request on vapor serverless while it works on local environment

Tags: laravel, mkdir, laravel-vapor

Image attached for reference in which it can be seen that, I hit API on vapor but MKDIR() not Laravel vapor and it is working on local perfectly.

[image: img]

```
function uploadFile($file, $path, $filename){
        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $file);
        list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        if (!\File::exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path);
        }
        if (\File::exists($path.'/'.$filename)) {
            \File::delete($path.'/'.$filename);
        }

        file_put_contents($path.'/'.$filename, $data);

    }
```

Comment: You need to share some code

Comment: function uploadFile($file, $path, $filename){
        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $file);
        list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        if (!\File::exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path);
        }
        if (\File::exists($path.'/'.$filename)) {
            \File::delete($path.'/'.$filename);
        }

        file_put_contents($path.'/'.$filename, $data);

    }

Comment: this is my function which uploads the file

Comment: Can you edit your question and put that code in the question itself and format it a bit. It's hard to tell what's happening here. However an overall comment is if you're using serverless architecture you should probably use another filesystem like S3 to store files because you can't rely that your containers or lambdas will persist the files you're storing

Comment: added my code to to question, i am wondering whether i can do it without including s3 bucket?

Comment: You could but your files will disappear seemingly randomly when containers are replaced and won't be available for all containers (I don't claim to understand vapor but I think it's works using some sort of containers or lambdas). You can try to use the 3rd parameter of `mkdir` to recursively create the directories that your directory needs to be created e.g. using `mkdir($path, 0777, true)` but again, you will have issues with file persistence so I do suggest using S3 as your main storage driver

Comment: thanks for the response. I am going to implement s3 bucket. Thanks.